# PostgreSQL SQL syntax - JOIN and substrings

Tags: postgresql, join, select, postgresql-9.2

I have a single table of hostnames and NFS exports, some but not all of which are related.
Example entries:

```
    HOST   VOLUME     
    -----  ---------- 
    host1  vol1
    host1  vol2
    host1  vol3
    host2  bkvol1_DR
    host2  bkvol2_DR
    host2  bkvol3_DR
```

I'm trying to create a query which will give me the following:

```
   SRCHOST  DSTHOST  SRCVOL    DSTVOL
   -------  -------  ------    ------
   host1    host2    vol1      bkvol1_DR
   host1    host2    vol2      bkvol2_DR
   host1    host2    vol3      bkvol3_DR
```

I've tried various incantations of substring(), trim(), and join clauses, and I'm getting nowhere. This is on PostgreSQL 9.2. In non-functional code, this is what I want:

```
select a.host, b.host, a.volume, b.volume from table as a, table as b 
    where a.volume is a substring of b.volume
```

Comment: How do you know that `host2` is the destination host for `host1`? I don't see how you can make that connection.

Comment: The "bkvol1_DR" volume exists only on host "host2", and is the target of "vol1" because the name "vol1" appears in the volume string.

Answer (score 4):

```
select a.host, b.host, b.volume
from hosts as a
  join hosts as b 
    on b.volume like '%'||a.volume||'%' 
   and a.host <> b.host;
```

Instead of `LIKE` you can also use `position` which might be easier to read:

```
select a.host, b.host, b.volume
from hosts as a
  join hosts as b 
    on a.host <> b.host
   and position(a.volume in b.volume) > 0
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a67c5/1